# Any way to know if UITextField is in the view's hierarchy?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am creating a UITextField-A inside an inputAccessoryView and when I call `[UITextField-A becomeFirstResponder]`, it would not work.  However, if I do it with a delay of 1 sec, it would work.  From what I searched, it is because the `UITextField` is not in the view's hierarchy yet.  So is there a way to know so I do not need to use the 1sec delay alternative?  Is there a `UITextFieldDidAppearInViewHierarchy` or somekind in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` offers a `didMoveToSuperview` method that you could abuse to do this.